# normal map with only one side does not work for me like this

Tags: uv, texture-painting, normal-map

I have a dragon model downloaded from the internet whose normal map shows only one side of the model with uv, I tried to do the same since painting the textures like that is easier, but when I make the normal map it doesn't work the same way and the shadows don't they are as I would like, I was wondering how they achieved this and if it is possible with blender.enter image description here

[image]

[image]

the model is of a dragon from skyrim and I find it fascinating how they managed to do this, how do I do the same?

[image]

This is how it looks when I try the same thing

[image]

Comment: Hello, are your UV islands correctly placed? Is your Image Texture with the normal map set to Non-Color instead of sRGB?

Comment: Mostly, you don't hand-paint normal maps.  You should think about using a bump map instead if you want to hand-paint.  Normal maps will usually be generated from other data, like from a bump map, or from a high poly sculpted mesh.

Comment: I don't paint the normal maps by hand and I have the map set to non-color, I generated the map using the bake from multiress tool, but it doesn't matter since i solved the problem even though I don't know how, and I don't know why it happened